# Where should Security Questions be stored?

Tags: php, security

Should Security Questions be stored with in the hard code on the page, or with in MySQL?
Or is there a better option yet?

the questions I'm talking about are what  user would answer in order to retrieve their password.

Comment: Do you mean user-defined security questions?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek yes, the questions that a user would answer in order to retrieve their password.

Comment: More expandable to store them in the db with a way to add more so that it won't require a developer to add more.

Comment: By retrieve password, do you mean reset it? because you shouldn't be able to retrieve the user's password.

Comment: @KevinB Okay, that is what I would think. But I was wondering if there was going to be some downside to doing it that way.

Comment: well, it requires more code, but i think the upsides outweigh the downsides. At least from a client point of view.

Comment: @KevinB I know that is the way sites do account recovery. 
But why is it bad to let them retrieve their password?

Comment: Websites often allow users to choose which question e.g., "pet's name", "town of birthplace", "favorite band", etc. With more than 1 choice, you would want to leverage a database to store the questions

Comment: @WhiteShadow - it depends how easy are user questions. Of course answers should be encrypted in database. But if question is simple aaa it won't help too much. I think the best option is not to use questions but simple giving possibility to generate new password if user gives his email. In that case you send email to user to given email (if user with this email exists) and when user clicks, he changes password. You can also send confirmation that password was changed to this email after changing.

Comment: At least, the answers to the security questions should be hashed and salted to, such that no one can gain the answers without breaking this security. (which should be the same for the passwords themself, so you might use a password encrypting library)

Comment: it's not about them retrieving it, it's more about it being possible to retrieve it at all. If the database is somehow compromised and the passwords are in a form that would allow you to retrieve them (ie plain text) all of the user's passwords would be compromised, where as if the passwords were properly hashed/salted, they would still be relatively safe.

Comment: @KevinB I see, you do make a good make a point.
I will salt both the Passwords and the Security Questions answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always keep the changeable data on Database. it's better to administration, security and integrity. I can't see a reason to keep this kind of data on a databese if you have one. 
I hope I've answered your question :)